# Persisting Query String Parameter Across Multiple Azure AD B2C Journeys

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm currently working with an Azure AD B2C tenant and facing a challenge related to token enrichment based on a query string parameter. Specifically, our goal is to extract the "AppTenantDomainName" from the query string and use it to enrich the token issued by Azure AD B2C.

To accomplish this, I've implemented a custom policy that captures the "AppTenantDomainName" from the query string and passes it to a REST API technical profile as an input claim. This claim is then persisted and included in the output claims, allowing us to enrich the token accordingly.

Initially, this setup works as expected. The REST API receives the "AppTenantDomainName" during the first call, enriches the token with the necessary claims, and these are verified and appear correct when inspected with tools like JWT.ms.

However, the issue arises with subsequent API calls. Despite the "AppTenantDomainName" being persisted, it is not present in the second call to the REST API; instead, the value is null, leading to the claims being overridden with null values.

I've confirmed that each API call has a unique correlation ID, indicating they are part of different instances of user journeys. My suspicion is that the second call originates from a TokenRefresh journey, which does not include the original query parameter "AppTenantDomainName", despite it being set as a persistent claim.

Given this setup is primarily for LocalAccount SignIn (without a SignUp step, as users are provisioned via the GraphAPI) which is in a Single ADB2C tenant, I'm seeking advice on how to ensure the tenant domain name persists across all journeys, including token refresh scenarios. Is there a way to maintain this query string parameter across different user journeys in Azure AD B2C, especially when the refresh token journey seems to omit it?

Any insights or solutions to ensure the persistence of this claim would be greatly appreciated.

To address the challenge of persisting the "AppTenantDomainName" across different user journeys in Azure AD B2C, including during token refresh scenarios, I took the following steps:

**Initial Strategy:** My initial approach was to add the persistent claim for the AppTenantDomainName across all technical profiles involved in both the User Sign-In Journey and the Token Refresh Journey. My expectation was that by marking the AppTenantDomainName as a persistent claim in these profiles, it would be reliably carried over and available across all subsequent API calls, including those for token refresh.

**Observations:** Despite this configuration, AppTenantDomainName persisted only for the initial sign-in flow. In subsequent token refresh calls, the tenant domain name was not included, resulting in its value being null in the API calls. This led to the override of previously set claims with null values, which was not the intended behavior. I expected the persistence setup to ensure the availability of the AppTenantDomainName across all journeys without fail.

**Alternative Approach:** As a temporary workaround, I devised a strategy involving the creation of multiple policies. In this approach, I appended the AppTenantDomainName as a suffix to the policyId, ensuring its presence in the REST API calls. This method guaranteed the persistence of the AppTenantDomainName across different journeys. However, this solution introduced significant maintenance overhead and scalability concerns, particularly when dealing with a large number of AppTenantDomainNames. It was clear that while this approach worked, it was not an ideal or sustainable solution.

In summary, my expectation was for the persistent claim configuration to seamlessly maintain the tenant domain name across all user journeys, including during token refreshes. When this expectation was not met, I resorted to a more manual and less scalable workaround. I am looking for a more streamlined and scalable solution to this challenge.

Comment: I have reached Azure support, and the ClaimTypes with default values cannot be persisted. I have managed to pass the query parameters from UI app for all adb2c end points.

Answer (score 0):

After consulting with Azure support, I learned that ClaimTypes that come with default values cannot be stored persistently in SSO session. My approach to overcoming this limitation involved retrieving the values directly from the query parameters. To implement a seamless solution, I decided to pass these query parameters from the UI application for every request made to the Azure AD B2C endpoints. This method ensures that the necessary data is available where it's needed without relying on the persistence of default ClaimTypes.